# Missing "New 3D Map View" in QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3

I was really curious about the new 3D-Map-View function of QGIS3. Now, finally, QGIS3 just released but I'm missing the 3D Map View! It should be at **View -> New 3D Map View** but it isn't.(https://anitagraser.com/2017/11/25/intro-to-qgis3-3d-view-with-viennese-building-data/)

[image]
[image]

Is it depending on my system configuration (Linux Mint 18.3 based on Ubuntu 16.04, Kernel 4.10)? Or have I overlooked a setting?

Comment: I don't have it either in my latest 2.99 version on Linux.  Wonder if it's been removed, due to issues llike: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17315 ?

Comment: I have it in my 2.99 (nightly) for windows.

Comment: What's your operating system? It works on my Ubuntu Angsty Aardvark, my system versions are similar except I'm running with Qt 5.9.1 compared to your 5.5.1.

Comment: Added: Linux Mint 18.3 based on Ubuntu 16.04, Kernel 4.10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

QGIS 3D requires at least Qt 5.8.

Comment: I'm running QT 5.5.1 - that should be the reason. I installed the 5.10 packages but 5.5.1 is still running. Maybe I have to purge all older QT-Packages? I'm not familiar with that... Any instructions?

Comment: It's not enough to just install the 5.10 packages - you'd need to rebuild qgis using them. I'd suggest waiting for your distro to upgrade the qt libraries, at which point you'll automatically get a new qgis package with this functionality. It's the trade off with using a distro with older packages in its repositories... You get older, more tested libraries, but will miss out on newer features as a result.