# QGIS 2.18 won't start up

Tags: qgis, linux

[Reinstalling QGIS on Linux Mint?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273457/reinstalling-qgis-on-linux-mint)

Most of my recent troubles are documented in the thread above, and I wasn't sure if I should just post this there. But here I am.

It just stopped working. It won't start. I hadn't used it in a few months and when I tried, nothing. I don't have a clue where to begin

Mint Cinnamon 17.3 64-bi
kernel 3.13.0-37-generic x86_64 (64 bit)

When I run it from command line I get:

```
ThinkPad-T410 ~ $ qgis
/usr/bin/qgis.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libltidsdk.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Edit 2: OK, I'm not sure I quite understand this but this is what I did and this is what I got:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/*libltidsdk*
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/*libltidsdk*: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Launch it from command line, you will have some outputs.

Comment: Did you try to install GDAL with MrSID support?

Comment: I dont recall trying to install Gdal, nor do I know how. I gave up on viewing orthos in Linux. When I need orthos I switch over and use Windows with Q 3.something. I suppose I could try again since at this point, I have no Q to lose...

Comment: Responding to your edit: ```ls /usr/lib/libltidsdk``` will *list* all files within the directory. But libltidsdk does not exist. Try ```ls /usr/lib/*libltidsdk*``` which will *list* all files withing */usr/lib/* that contain *libltidsdk*.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize in your second edit that the asterisks were there. I edited your post to format the code.

Comment: I think @AndreJ was on the right track, *libltidsdk.so* is a library from MrSID. Why not trying reinstalling MrSID or otherwise repairing the install.

Comment: My last attempt at MrSid did not end well...https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=269122

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your attempt to install MrSID "did not end well", you should get rid of the self-compiled stuff.

It might be that your OS is too old to support current the LizardTech codebase. So remove everything that is self-compiled, and install GDAL and QGIS 2.14 from the ubuntugis-unstable ppa as long as they support trusty. If that works, upgrade to QGIS 2.18 from https://qgis.org/ubuntugis

If you need MrSID support, install a more recent Linux Mint in a virtual box, and test the self-compiling there. If it works, think of upgrading your OS.

Comment: Yeah i think  will just pass on doing anything.  I will be getting ArcGis shortly for a class I'm taking, and MrSid already works on the Windows QGIS side. So I think I'll just wait until I get a new laptop and new Mint sometime later next year.

Answer (score 2):

`libltidsdk.so` is a dependency. It should be a symbolic link to the current version called something like `libltidsdk.so.20.0.0`. If the symbolic link was broken during an update you can relink it using a method similar to [here](https://elza.me/blog/2015/09/QGIS/). Instead of `libgdal.so` figure out the needed link for `libltidsdk.so`.

In my experience, dependencies break here and there for qgis and this method always seems to do the trick.